# Can I use wildcards for blocking websites in hosts files?

Tags: macos, web, host

I'd like to block websites in my hosts file with wildcards. I know that I can block websites by adding them like this

```
0.0.0.0 website.com
::      website.com
```

I'd like to block websites in regex. I heard it's possible to do this with DNS.

Can I do this with the hosts file?

Comment: This is not a programming question. May be on-topic on SU or SF sites of the StackExchage network.

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/135595/using-wildcards-in-names-in-windows-hosts-file and https://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain

Comment: Using the `hosts` file to block websites is not particularly effective because it only blocks name-resolution - malicious software and websites can still serve themselves by IP address or on another (possibly randomly-generated) domain-name. If you're on macOS you should use Little Snitch: https://obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

Comment: Can you use Little Snitch to add filters?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: No.

**Longer answer**: No, but you can if you use a DNS proxy or local DNS server instead.

The `hosts` file format used by Windows, most Linux distributions, and macOS does not support wildcards.

(I say "most" Linux distributions because I'm sure there's some long-abandoned fork of Slackware that probably has this feature).

That said, DNS servers' zone-files *do* tend to support wildcards (including BIND's `named.conf`). In which case the solution is to run your own DNS server locally - or at least a DNS proxy server that you can configure to override the responses for configured domain names.

Comment: Great! Can you provide instructions on editing a local DNS server?

Comment: @Cauder Yes, for an extortionately high hourly rate.

Comment: @Cauder As you're on a Mac, you **should** use Little Snitch rather than a custom DNS server: https://obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

Comment: Great, appreciate it! Do you mind providing a reason why you prefer Little Snitch?

Comment: @Cauder Because it sounds like you want to block specific connections - and Little Snitch is the best tool to do that. Messing around with your `hosts` file is *not* the best way to block connections on your computer.

Comment: Great! Can you please see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61714875/how-to-create-custom-rules-in-little-snitch